# MySqli not loading characters with diacritics

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, character-encoding, phpmyadmin

I have a database, and for example the letter `é` from db is returned as `Ã©` or `î` is returned on a page as `Ã®`. This happend also for `a`. How to make it work??

This is the table in PHPMyAdmin
[image: This is the table in PHPMyAdmin]

And this is the page showing the weird characters:

[image: The page showing the weird characters]

Comment: database character encoding is set to...? and php page encoding is set to...?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy http://img.ctrlv.in/img/14/05/24/538101904c4c2.png  i think utf-8 unicode... this table where the error is, its called `personalitati`

Comment: Excellent. Then you just need to add the UTF-8 charset to your PHP page as well.

Comment: and how to do that? o.0

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">` is one way.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the `ini_set` as well. `ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8')`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy wait... but now the `î` that were on site before and were working, transformed in `�`

Comment: Ahh, I see why. your table is actually `Latin-1`. So instead, try using, `charset=ISO-8859-1` as your charset. Alternatively you can use `mb_convert_encoding` to change the multibyte encoding of the strings before you print them. You can also set the charset type in the mysql query as well.

Comment: how to set the charset in mysql?

Comment: and if i will, what charset should i set on page with meta?

Comment: Okay. Revert the code back to `UTF-8` and use `mysql_set_charset("utf8");` or `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");` or `mysqli_set_charset($dbConnection, "utf8");`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy again appears �

Comment: Is the file "saved as" UTF-8 and without BOM?

Comment: @Fred -ii- it is saved as UTF-8 but what is BOM?

Comment: A byte order mark. Google that.

Comment: ok, saw it. but how to check it out?

Comment: You're best to get a copy of Notepad++ and then open the file and you'll see under the "encoding" dropdown menu. => http://notepad-plus-plus.org/ it's free and works well.

Comment: NetBeans has this feature?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does.

Comment: wait... I have the same files on a localhost server with xampp, and without using any meta tag, all the characters were shown correctly

Comment: ok. so wait... Now i have meta with charset=UTF-8 and all the diacritics from db work fine, but the diacritics from site template are replaced by �. The new question is: Can i use hex codes for î and â? And it will return the char or a �?

Comment: You'll have to try it out and see. You can also use ASCII codes/HTML codes. See this chart => http://www.ascii-code.com/